# Is surname Ede of Northern European origin and rare in England?

Tags: surnames, united-kingdom, europe

I am trying to identify my British great-grandfather. I have investigated him in Japan and narrowed the candidates down to eight. I then checked those eight candidates in detail; seven of them seem not to match, and only one candidate stayed. He is C.Z. Ede (Cecil Zohrab Ede). I checked into him and there is some circumstantial evidence indicating that he is my great-grandfather. However, there is no decisive evidence.

A DNA test (Family Tree DNA-Family Finder) said that a Danish man was a cousin to me but when I tried to contact him no reply came back.

I want to be more sure of my relationship to him.  My British friend says that Ede may be a family name of North European origin, and I understand that the family name of Ede is rare in the U.K.

Is it true?

Comment: Ede may be an English surname, but it's not just an English surname. Wikipedia has a disambiguation page for Ede [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ede ]. Ede as a surname could be derived from the placename Ede in the Netherlands (and Nigeria) or from the given name Edward. In the surname section of the page, there are people from England, Nigeria, Netherlands, etc. In the given name section, the individuals are Hungarian. Note - before WW1, Trieste was part of the Austro-Hungarian empire.

Comment: Ede is English surname.I found it. My Origin is Scandinavia by FTDNA(Family Finder).                                                                                             [link](http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Ede)
[link](http://forebears.co.uk/surnames/ede#meaning)
Is my origin Scandinavia? 
I want to know C.Z.Ede is my great-grandfather or not.
Is there good way to check?
Now I am stuck.

Comment: There are three reasonable questions embedded in this question, but they are completely unrelated: (1) Ede surname origin, (2) Edward Ede working in Trieste, (3) Using UK vs USA DNA company. Can we settle on one of these for this question, and trim out all the other superfluous information/questions. Akira has asked quite a few questions on this site but few of them have answers just because they are a bit unclear, not because they are all bad questions

Comment: @vervet I agree that any time we can see a single question per question it makes the approach to answering more straightforward. Comments suggest that the origin of the Ede surname is where we have already commenced formulating answers so I would support you trimming as suggested and will otherwise do it myself. If Akira were to trim it himself that would be even better of course.

Comment: @Akira Now that this question has been focussed on the "Ede surname origin", you may want to ask a separate question on "Edward Ede working in Trieste" or "Using UK vs USA DNA company".

Answer (score 2):

From the [Forebears website the surname Ede](http://forebears.io/surnames/ede) appears to be more common in England than in other Northern European countries.

The "[Surnames of England and Wales - the ONS list](http://www.taliesin-arlein.net/names/search.php)" website says that there were 2365 people named Ede in England and Wales in September 2002, making it the 3,191st most common surname in that dataset.

Comment: I can understand your opinion.But I have became know who is my great-grandfather. I investigated in Japan. I investigated every English men. Then  C.Z.Ede stayed as a candidate. I tried FTDNA. But I can't decide he is my great-grandfather. He had many circumstantial evidences. Is there good way to find my great-grandfather. I visit library many times. And I went to Manchester library. But I couldn't find the evidences.

Comment: @Akira I think one of the best ways to uncover genealogical and family facts is by asking questions here, but when you do please try to ask only one question per question, as per the [Tour], and to use the [help/on-topic] to learn more about how best to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot more success with contacting distant cousins through DNA by using the MyHeritage DNA service. You do not need to take another test just upload your data from FTDNA to MyHeritage. You do not even need a pay account at MyHeritage to do this. It is worth a try.

Also have you uploaded your DNA to GedMatch?

[Link to MyHeritage](https://www.myheritage.com/dna)

[Link to Gedmatch](https://www.gedmatch.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it once. Then I registered my DNA in GedMatch but I do not know how to use it. I do not have that knowledge because I will not do a match using DNA in Japan. The woman who helped me when I stayed in England two years ago had a detailed book on DNA and she used to go to a study group looking for an ancestor.

Answer (score -1):

I thought that this might Help:

Surname Database: Ede Last Name Origin
www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Ede
Last name: Ede. This interesting surname is of early medieval English origin, and derives from Eda, a Middle English pet form of the female given name Edith, itself coming from the Olde English pre 7th Century "Eadgyth", a compound of the elements "ead", prosperous, and "gyth", battle.
Ede Name Meaning, Family History, Family Crest & Coats of Arms
https://www.houseofnames.com/ede-family-crest
The origins of the name Ede are with the Anglo-Saxon tribes of Britain. The name is derived from the son of Ede, as Edison, which was later shortened to Eadie.